# Header div opacity not showing on Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, opacity

I have a header div on my page which is positioned:fixed and by default, set to 50% transparent and as you scroll down, the transparency fades into its opaque state. Now the default 50% transparency is not set thru CSS directly but rather thru the JS function below. In Chrome, the 50% transparency shows perfectly and fades fine as well as you scroll down. But in Firefox, when the page loads, the 50% transparency is not there but when you scroll down,the opaque state shows and when you scroll back up, the transparency comes up but I want that to be there as soon as the page loads in Firefox.

I tried to use filter:opacity=x but that is only for IE. RGBA is supported by all browsers so that's not the issue and I also used -moz-transition vendor prefix but that did not work either.

JS:
window.onscroll = scroll;

```
function scroll() {
    var header=document.getElementById("header1");

    console.log(window.pageYOffset);
    if(window.pageYOffset > 50){
        console.log("Change Opacity now");
        header.classList.add('setOpaqueState');
        header.classList.remove('removeOpaqueState');
    }
    else{
        header.classList.remove('setOpaqueState');
        header.classList.add('removeOpaqueState');
    }

}

CSS:

.homepage #header1 {
transition: background 1.0s;
}
.homepage .setOpaqueState {
background-color: #261c3f;
}
.homepage .removeOpaqueState {
background-color: rgba(38, 28, 63, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/YuJ7y/ Can you please elaborate?

Comment: this worked on firefox?

Comment: Yep, Firefox 30 and Nightly (OSX)

Comment: hmmm...is putting window.scroll = scroll; outside of the function the issue? I would not think so but my problem could be something related to the function because essentially the default background is getting set from the if else conditon

Comment: Show a complete, minimal example, then

Comment: actually, I did not put class="removeOpaqueState" in the header but then how is it that it works fine in chrome? sorry to be persistant but it's a simple I've been stuck with for the last day